# Data not inserted into database table with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

I have a bit of a problem, Im trying to insert a row into a database table, everything looks like it's working fine.My debugger doesn't find anything and neither does my catch(SQLException) but nothing is saved to database.

This is my insert code:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO files_authorised(auth_id,level,notify,level_user,approval_status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setString(1, auth_id);
        stmt.setInt(2, level);
        stmt.setString(3, notify);
        stmt.setInt(4, level_user);
        stmt.setString(5, approval_status);
        System.out.println(query);

        stmt.executeUpdate();
```

The values being send as parameters are fine, I printed them and the are exactly as I want them.

Thanks in advance. If you need any further info just comment.

Comment: Tried inserting the static values , to make sure the query is running fine . Else try it using the sql developer

Comment: I tried it with static value but my catch get's it, I printed the query and inserted it into my mysql developer and it adds the row fine

Comment: Are you sure that you get all values . Also check the datatypes (setString and setInt) methods

Comment: Do you call commit() after invoking the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't insert

```
con.commit();
```

This was the first time this problem has occurred while inserting into a database.

Answer by StanislavL
Thansks StanislavL